# Facebook 'tab' application built in Flash needing deeplinking

Tags: facebook, flash, swfaddress

I'm working on a Facebook tab application that is built in Flash. Since the Facebook tab is actually an iframe withpulling in an HTML page on my server that houses the SWF, my deeplinking in my SWF is not working.

I'm using SWFAddress successfully when viewing the SWF in it's original HTML page, but my SWFAddress events are changing the URL of that original HTML page, not the Facebook url.

Can I deeplink with SWFAddress in a SWF that is being displayed on Facebook with an iframe? How? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. There are two alternatives which come to my mind:

1. Use serverside code to read the app_data parameter from the [Facebook signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).
2. Work with cookies. Set a cookie with JavaScript and read it with JavaScript. This way you can "fake" deeplinking.

Comment: Thanks, Lego. Both sound like good options. I ended up going with an HTML-based solution and using the `app_data` parameter.